# How to control dynamically created components using Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

On my project I am working on I am trying to control dynamically created Material UI components. For example I am looping and pushing many components into a Material Table.

```
  for (let i = 0; i < daysBetweenDates + 1; i++) {
        let startDateCopy = startDate;
        tableData.push([
            <div className={classes.displayFlex}>
                <IconButton size="small">
                    <ClearIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <IconButton size="small">
                    <FileCopyIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </div>,
            <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                <KeyboardDatePicker
                    disableToolbar
                    variant="inline"
                    size="small"
                    format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                    margin="normal"
                    value={startDateCopy.setDate(startDateCopy.getDate() + 1)}
                    onChange={handleDateChange}
                    KeyboardButtonProps={{
                        'aria-label': 'change date',
                    }}
                />
            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>,
            <TextField  size="small" variant="outlined" />, //shift start
            <TextField size="small" variant="outlined" />, //shift length
            <Typography>--MT</Typography>, //autocalculated shift end time
            <TextField size="small" variant="outlined" />,
            <TextField size="small" variant="outlined" />,
            <Typography>--MT</Typography>,
            <Typography>Salt Lake City</Typography>,
            <Typography>English</Typography>,

        ]);
```

I have to manipulate these fields in many ways, such as if they hit the File Copy Icon I need to recreate the row and add it to the table. If they enter times into the first two TextFields (shift start and shift length) then I need to autocalculate their end time and change the first Typography to that end time. At first I tried holding onto a single startTime state variable but then it changed all of the rows at once. I thought about holding rows of data on state but that seems like a lot to hold on state and manage. Or is it better to give them Id's and track and manipulate them that way.

I am using React, Material UI, TypeScript. 
Thank you!

Edit: Here is the code sandbox, had to remove styling but you can see how I am populating the data and how it will be used.
https://codesandbox.io/embed/elastic-blackwell-1r1jj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Can you please have code sandbox link for your code

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/elastic-blackwell-1r1jj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Keep in mind that if you wrap all those Material UI components representing a row in `tableData` you then can manage the numerous operations for each in row in a more structured way. Make a `TableRow` component that emits events to the `Table` component where it can copy rows (add another item to state array value), remove rows (remove item from state array value), etc.

Comment: Ok so instead of simply having a table component that maps through and creates the table rows, it would be better if I created a TableRow component and passed an array of those to the separate Table component, and hold this array on state?

Comment: It's a matter of opinion, but doing things like `handleDateChange` inside of TableRow component where it has access to all it's own data will be easier than in the Table component.